# NVelocity macro parameter not evaluating

Tags: .net, vb.net, velocity, nvelocity

I'm looking to create an inline function (method) inside my NVelocity template.  The solution to this appears to be to use [Velocimacros](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#velocimacros).  So, I mocked up the following template to test:

```
#macro( getOutput $one $two $three )
<td>$one</td>
<td>$two.Item2</td>
<td>$three</td>
#end

<table>
#foreach( $item in $mdl.Items )

    <tr>
        #set( $one1 = $item.Item1 )
        #getOutput( $one1 $item $item.Item3 )  ## item.Item3 won't evaluate!
    </tr>

#end
</table>
```

`$mdl` is my base Model object, which for this example contains one property, `Items`, which is a `List(Of Tuple(Of String, Integer, Date))`.  Populated with test data like so:

```
Dim items As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, Integer, DateTime))
With items
   .Add(New Tuple(Of String, Integer, DateTime)("One", 1, #1/1/2001#))
   .Add(New Tuple(Of String, Integer, DateTime)("Two", 2, #2/2/2002#))
   .Add(New Tuple(Of String, Integer, DateTime)("Three", 3, #3/3/2003#))
End With
```

When I run the template, the problem I'm having is that the output from the macro parameter `$three` is literally "$item.Item3" instead of evaluating to #3/3/2003#.  (BTW - this happens with any of the 3 items in the tuple if they are passed with the `.Item` call, so it isn't about the data type).

I can make a variable and pass it just fine ($one1).  I can pass the tuple itself and call the .Item property inside the macro ($item.Item2), but for some reason I cannot call the `.Item` property when passing the argument to the macro.  Any insight?

Comment: No, I totally did not.  I just had to do a work around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like NVelocity macro support is limited.

http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/problems.html#macros

An alternative would be to use Helpers:

[NVelocity extension method ASP.NET webform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082908/nvelocity-extension-method-asp-net-webform)